# Data cleaning in array of objects: cannot get for loop working

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array of objects with some data I need to tidy up. The data looks like this:

```
 var transferCodeArray = [
   {
      "code": "345",
      "amount": "t 4,4345.00"
   },
   {
      "code": "456",
      "amount": "t 35,564.00"
   }
]
```

I am trying to loop through the array and split, shift, join, and trim all values in the amount key.  The function I wrote is below, but I can't get it working:

```
function cleanData() {
  for(var i = 0; i < transferCodeArray.length; i++) {
    var amt = transferCodeArray[i].details.amount;
    for(var j = 0; j < amt.length; j++){
      if(amt[j] !== null) {
        amt[j].split("").shift().join("").trim();
      } 
    }
  }
}
cleanData();
```

I *think* my issue is with defining the 'j' value in the second for loop. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `var amt = transferCodeArray[i].details.amount;` remove details...

Comment: When you are looping in an array you should loop using `for(var i in transferCodeArray)`

Comment: the result, how should it look like?

Comment: I wanted to remove the leading character and spaces. @Tushar's map function, with a little tweak to the regex, worked well.

Comment: You can chain those methods like jQuery? `amt[j].split("").shift().join("").trim();`

Answer (score -2):

b=[];
transferCodeArray.map(function(x){
  return b.push({code:x.code, amount:parseFloat(x.amount.split(' ')[1].replace(',',''))});

});